# How can I inflate MapView from an non UI tread

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-3.0-honeycomb

My app  uses HoneyComb fragments where my left side panel has listview and right side panel has a MapView with some TextViews.Initially i wrote map view in the map_fragment_right_side.xml which resulted in freezing the screen for long time ,so I decided to inflate the map view at runtime in an AsyncTask in vain .The code goes like this

```
class LoadMapTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>
{

    MapView inflatedMapView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        progressbar.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );

    }


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params)
    {


        try{

        inflatedMapView = new MapView(getActivity(),getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.mapkey));

        addMapViewhere.addView(inflatedMapView);


        inflatedMapView.getController().setCenter(getPoint(Double.valueOf(latitude),Double.valueOf(longitude)));

        inflatedMapView.getController().setZoom(17);

        inflatedMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        sites=new SitesOverlay();

        inflatedMapView.getOverlays().clear();

        inflatedMapView.getOverlays().add(sites);

        }catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return true;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean res)
    {
        if( progressbar != null )
        {
            progressbar.setVisibility( View.GONE );
        }






    }

}
```

I doubt whether its possible to inflate map view from non-UI thread .I will be glad if someone suggest me the right way to do this.I don't want the screen to freeze until map gets loaded. 
thanks,
ganesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inflate it from `onPreExecute()` or in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: yes i agree with you Nikola ,I was desperate to find a solution to the slow loading map view in HoneyComb.